# Why is the constructor not the constructing function?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following snippet:

```
​f = function() {};
f.prototype = {};
thing = new f;
```

I was surprised to see that `thing.constructor​` is `Object()`. (See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh9hW/).)

Why isn't `thing.constructor` the function `f`?
​

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you've entirely replaced the original `prototype` object of `f` with a plain object. It was the original `prototype` object that held the reference to `f` via the `.constructor` property.

The constructor of an object created using object literal syntax will be the `Object` constructor.

To get it back, you'd need to put it there manually.

```
f = function() {};
f.prototype = {};
f.prototype.constructor = f;
thing = new f;
```

This will shadow the `.constructor` property on in the prototype chain of the new prototype object.

If you delete that property, you'll get `Object` again.

```
delete f.prototype.constructor;

console.log(thing.constructor); // Object
```