# JavaScript Inheritance - Am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

### Questions:

1. Why does the first method correctly identify the object as Ferrari?
   (tested in Chrome)
2. Am I doing inheritance correctly in the two methods?
3. Am I correct in understanding that there are some hidden "constructor" properties in the first example, if so where are they, and what put them there?  Are there any hidden constructor properties in the second example I didn't explicitly put in?
4. Providing I have done inheritance correctly, which of the two methods at the end should I use to let the object be identified as a Ferrari?  Or should I not care - after all "instanceof" still works?

### Context:

**Using JavaScript's "new" method for creating objects, works fine:**

```
Vehicle.prototype = {}; // Not required I know
function Vehicle() {

}

Car.prototype = new Vehicle();
function Car() {

}

Ferrari.prototype = new Car();
function Ferrari() {

}
var o = new Ferrari();
console.log(o);
```

**Which outputs:**

```
> Ferrari
  > __proto__ : Car
    > __proto__ : Vehicle
      > __proto__ : Object <- The one that isn't required
        > __proto__ : Object <- Provided by JS
          ...
          hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
          ...
```

**Now I want to do the same thing avoiding the new keyword, here's what I've got:**

```
Vehicle.prototype = {};
function Vehicle() {
  var vehicle = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
  return vehicle;
}

Car.prototype = Vehicle();
Car.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;
function Car() {
  var car = Object.create(Car.prototype);
  return car;
}

Ferrari.prototype = Car();
Ferrari.prototype.constructor = Car;

function Ferrari() {
  var ferrari = Object.create(Ferrari.prototype);
  //ferrari.constructor = Ferrari;  <- Lookey here - commented line
  return ferrari;
}

var o = new Ferrari();
console.log(o);
```

**Which outputs:**

```
> **Car**
  > __proto__ : Car
    > constructor : function Car()
      __proto__ : Vehicle
      > constructor : function Vehicle()
        __proto__ : Object <- The one that isn't required
        > __proto__ : Object
          ...
          hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
          ...
```

*Notice the first line of the output is now a Car, rather than Ferrari.  That can be rectified by removing the commented line, or by changing the Ferrari's prototype as follows:*

```
var realPrototype = Car();
realPrototype.constructor = Car;

Ferrari.prototype = Object.create(realPrototype);
Ferrari.prototype.constructor = Ferrari;
```

Comment: You're setting `Ferrari.prototype.constructor` to `Car`. But the point of resetting `constructor` is that instances of `Ferrari` have their constructor set back to `Ferrari` instead of `Car` (which happens automatically when overwriting `prototype`).

Comment: @pimvdb the reason I didn't do that is because in the second method it would appear (in the object graph) that the prototype of Ferrari is a Ferrari, when in fact it is the "instance of a Car".  Interestingly, when you do the same thing to the first method it doesn't change the graph at all! - The inconsistency suggests to me it's not the correct way of doing inheritance?

Comment: @Lee This way of doing inheritance is fine, you just have to set the constructor of each subtype to the parent. You can either save yourself a bit of trouble and do this inside the function body, or you can reset the constructor each time you make a prototype for a subtype. See my answer. Also, the prototype of **`o`** is `Ferrari`, the prototype of `Ferrari` **isn't** `Ferrari`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the first method correctly identify the object as Ferrari? (tested in Chrome)
>
> Am I correct in understanding that there are some hidden "constructor" properties in the first example, if so where are they, and what put them there? Are there any hidden constructor properties in the second example I didn't explicitly put in?

Yes, it seems Chrome sets a hidden "constructor" property if you assign to a function's `prototype` property, or create a new instance somehow. Haven't figured it out exactly.

Where they are? Probably some internal properties to which only `console.log` has access to. Yet, you seem to be able to overwrite them with an explicit "constructor" property, at least for the displaying of `__proto__` objects.

I guess this is done by Chrome as many people forget to set the constructor property (because [it's actually useless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572)) when overwriting prototype objects, though it [is recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4944278/1048572) - see also [JavaScript inheritance and the constructor property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8093057/1048572). Chrome Devs wanted to make a pretty `log` function that indicates the type of the object, so they needed to work around people's lazyness.

> Am I doing inheritance correctly in the two methods?

There is no problem with inheritance in your code. Newly created `Car` instances have the aspired prototype chain, with both methods.

Though, there are some pitfalls. Don't use the `new` keyword to create prototype <s>objects</s> instances. You don't want full-fledged instances, with a constructor applied on them. Just use `Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype)`; see also the answers on [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)

Also, you did not set the "constructor" properties, or did it wrong. That property, defined on prototype objects, is inherited by all objects created by a `new` call to the respective constructor function, and it should provide them a reference to exactly that function. This is done by default for any created function, see [EcmaScript specification §13.2 steps 16-18](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2).

If you reassign to `fn.prototype`, you overwrite that behaviour (regardless whether it's an object literal, a `new` construction or a `Object.create` call). Effectively, the "constructor" property is then [inherited from an object higher up in the prototype chain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12394972/1048572) - in your first example `o.constructor` is `Object`, inherited from the empty object literal. So, we need to reset it after the assignment, in your case:

```
Vehicle.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;
Car.prototype.constructor = Car;
Ferrari.prototype.constructor = Ferrari;

// or, we combine it with the Object.create call:
Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype, {
    constructor: {value:Car, configurable:true, writable:true}
});
```

Notice that there is no need to set it explicitly in the constructor (as in your second example), creating an extra property on the object. This is what inheritance is made for.

Or we don't care about "constructor" properties at all:

> Which of the two methods at the end should I use to let the object be identified as a Ferrari? Or should I not care - after all "instanceof" still works?

To identify an object as a Ferrari always use `instanceof`. The "constructor" property is not reliable. It might have been forgotten to set, or it is not what you expected in a comparison: A "type check" like `someObj.constructor === Car` won't work for Ferraris or any other "subclasses" that have their constructor properties properly set. It does with `instanceof`.

Answer (score -1):

> **Why does the first method correctly identify the object as Ferrari?**

Because the constructor for the object `o` is the function `Ferrari`.

> **Am I doing inheritance correctly in the two methods?**

You are doing it correctly in the first method, but not so correctly in the second.

> **Providing I have done inheritance correctly, which of the two methods at the end should I use to let the object be identified as a
>   Ferrari? Or should I not care - after all "instanceof" still works?**

For uniformity, you should be setting the constructor property on each prototype *within* the function body, so that you don't have to do:

```
Car.prototype = Vehicle();
Car.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;

Aeroplane.prototype = Vehicle();
Aeroplane.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;

...
```

Instead you should be using:

```
function Vehicle() {
    var vehicle = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
    vehicle.constructor = Vehicle;
    return vehicle;
}

Car.prototype = Vehicle();
function Car() {
    var car = Object.create(Car.prototype);
    car.constructor = Car;
    return car;
}

Ferrari.prototype = Car();
function Ferrari() {
    var ferrari = Object.create(Ferrari.prototype);
    ferrari.constructor = Ferrari;
    return ferrari;
}

var o = new Ferrari();
console.log(o);
```

This correctly results in a structure similar to the one in your first example.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. Why set the property in the constructor when it can easily be inherited?

Comment: @Bergi The `constructor` property of the object you are using as a prototype needs to be reset each time in the code the OP has posted. For example, if I have 10 types of vehicles, each time I set the prototype of the new vehicle to `Vehicle()`, I would also need to do `Motorcycle.prototype.constructor = Vehicle;`. The way I'm doing it the `constructor` property is already set.

Comment: Nah, `Motorcycle.prototype.constructor` should be `Motorcycle`. What I wanted to ask why you are doing `car.constructor = Car` (for each instance) instead of `Car.prototype.constructor = Car` (once).

Comment: @Bergi No, `Motorcycle.prototype.constructor` should be `Vehicle`. The `constructor` property of an Object's prototype should point to the function that created that prototype. To quote MDN (regarding `constructor`): `Returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.` `Car` is an instance of a `Vehicle`, so its constructor is `Vehicle`.

Comment: Doing `Car.prototype.constructor = Car` would do a completely different thing from `car.constructor = Car`. It would be incorrect to set the constructor of an instance to itself. `Car` is constructed by `Vehicle`, not by itself.

Comment: Sure, that is one of the odds why prototype objects should not be instances of anything (and no, the function `Car` is never an instance of `Vehicle`). However, you seem to have misunderstood the [MDN text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). What it wants to express is "*a functions prototype object has a property 'constructor', which references that function the prototype was created for*" - so that all instances inherit this property, pointing to their constructor.

Comment: @Bergi "*A functions prototype object has a property 'constructor', which references that function the prototype was created for.*" This is simply not true. It contradicts what is being stated pretty explicitly: the `constructor` property of a function's prototype points to the constructor of it's prototype.  It is that simple. Doing `Car.prototype.constructor = Car` would imply the constructor of the prototype of `Car` is `Car`, whereas it is in fact `Vehicle`.

Comment: Only if you created it by `new Vehicle`, which you shouldn't. Please have a look on the EcmaScript spec for how the "constructor" property should work. If you have an arbitrary function `fn`, then `fn.prototype.constructor === fn`. Even though `fn.prototype` is obviously constructed by `Object` - but the inherited `Object.prototype.constructor` (`Object`) is shadowed/overwritten.